# Swift: Invoking subclass function in base class version of init

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift, how can you invoke a subclass's function in the base class's `init` method? Essentially, the goal is to ensure each subclass invokes its own version of `initGrid`, and then all the code to set `numRows` and `numCols` is defined only once, in the base class.

However, when initializing a subclass, the `initGrid` function from the base class -- not the subclass -- is run instead. This results in an array index exception since `grid` is empty unless the subclass creates it.

```
class BaseGrid {
    var grid = [[NodeType]]()
    var numRows = 0
    var numCols = 0


    init() {
        // Init grid
        initGrid()

        // Set <numRows>
        numRows = grid.count

        // Set <numCols>
        numCols = grid[0].count

        // Verify each row contains same number of columns
        for row in 0..<numRows {
            assert(grid[row].count == numCols)
        }
    }


    // Subclasses override this function
    func initGrid() {}
}


class ChildGrid: BaseGrid {


    override init() {
        super.init()
    }


    override func initGrid() {
        grid = [
                [NodeType.Blue, NodeType.Blue, NodeType.Blue],
                [NodeType.Red, NodeType.Red, NodeType.Red],
                [NodeType.Empty, NodeType.Blue, NodeType.Empty]
               ]
    }

}
```

Comment: This prints "Subclass" for me: https://gist.github.com/jawwad/1ee4347debd082a3c768

Comment: Thanks @Jawwad, but this doesn't work for us. Question now contains code for subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you will subclass and override initGrid, it will call method in current scope.
In base class, you can stay it empty, as abstract.
I.e.:

```
class AdvancedGrid: BaseGrid {
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    override func initGrid() {
        // here is you custom alghoritm
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't work for some reason. Updated the question with code of subclass. Any clues?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Yes the code compiles if that is the question.

Comment: Also, the question now contains code for the subclass, which contains the code for building the grid, but some reason it's not getting called.

Comment: see now you changes, so what the issue?
If prints correct - change title, or close it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74135/discussion-between-dimpiax-and-crashalot).

Comment: Never mind, sorry, we found the error, and it's not related to this. Thanks anyway. Will close this question. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, can we chat for a bit, @dimpiax? Want to ask you a quick question re consulting. @Jawwad, we were calling BaseGrid() instead of ChildGrid(). Stupid. :)

Comment: @Crashalot re-entered ;)